# uploaded an existing pycharm project into github and now it doesnt run

Tags: github, scrapy, pycharm

newb alert. I'm new to GitHub so this might be a dumb question. I was creating a web scraper with scrapy on PyCharm & asked my friend for some help so I uploaded it into GitHub. Everything went fine until I realized that 1. the entire file was moved into a local file (previously was inside of pycharm & 2. it wouldn't run. When I inspected both files I came to find that there was only one key thing missing. There was a 'scrapy.cgf' file that was the only file not moved into the new local file.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I'm having a difficult time following. Are you saying that your `scrapy.cgf` file wasn't uploaded to GitHub and so, when your friend cloned the repository, it failed to run due to that missing dependency? If so, it _may_ be because you setup a `.gitignore` file, and your `scrapy.cgf` file is being excluded. (The `.gitignore` file instructs git to ignore particular files. It is typically used for compiled output, user-specific configuration, secure content, or external dependencies.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.